# How to handle generic inheritance

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I have this code for example

```
public class BaseClass
{}

public class DerivedClass1 : BaseClass
{}

public class DerivedClass2 : BaseClass
{ }

public class DerivedClass3 : BaseClass
{ }

public class GenericBaseClass<T> where T : BaseClass
{
    public List<T> collection { get; set; }
}
```

Now I'd like to create a new class which would inherit from `GenericBaseClass<T>` and have somehow a collection List in this class.

Is this even possible this way ? 
Because `List<BaseClass> = new List<DerivedCLass3>();` isn't valid.

Or the only way to achieve this is to remove the `collection` property from the `GenericBaseClass` and add a collection List directly in the derived class.

I hope I expressed myself understandable as English isn't my first language :-)

Comment: You said "I'd like to create a new class which would inherit from GenericBaseClass<T>".  What is "T"?  "T" is only in scope inside the declaration of GenericBaseClass<T>.  Do you mean that you want the derived class to be a nested class inside GenericBaseClass<T>?  Or do you mean that you want to declare a different generic type that has a different T?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class GenericBaseClass<T> where T : BaseClass
{
    public List<T> collection { get; set; }
}

public class GenericDerivedClass1 : GenericBaseClass<DerivedClass1>
{
    // Here the collection property will be of type List<DerivedClass1>
}
```

Comment: I use this GenericBaseClass<T> as a parameter type in one method and I'm unable to pass GenericDerivedClass1 as the parameter value. Is there any way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your sample code can't compile is due to covariance.  .Net can't handle auto typing of a class that is less specific than itself.  I believe this is all changing in .Net 4.5 though and what you are trying to do may in fact be supported.

[Covariance and contravariance (computer science)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29)